# virtual memory effects and relations between paging and segmentation

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

This is my first post. I want to ask about how are virtual memory related to paging and segmentation. I am searching internet for few days, but still can't manage to put that information into right order. Here is what I know so far:

We can talk about addresses (we could say they are levels of memory abstraction) in memory:

- **physical level** (CPU talking to memory controller, "hey give me contents of address 0xFFEABCD", these adresses are adresses of cells in RAM, so cell 0xABCD has physical address 0xABCD. memory controller can only use physical adresses, so if adress is not physical it must be changed to physical.
- **logical level**.This is abstraction over physical addresses. Here processes if ask for memory, (assume successfull allocation) are given address which has no direct relation to cells in RAM. We can say these addresses are from different pool (world?) than physical addresses. As I said before memory controller only understand physical adresses, so to use logical addresses, we need to convert them to physical addresses. There are two ways for OS to be able to create logical adresses:

  - **paging** - in which physical memory (RAM) is divided into continous blocks of memory (called frames), and logical memory (this other world) is also divided in same in length blocks (called pages). Now OS keep in RAM data structure called page table. It's an associative array (map) and it's primary goal of existence is to translate logical level addresses to physical level adresses. Paging has following effect: memory allocated by process in RAM (so in frames in physical memory belonging to program) may not be in contingous manner (so there may be holes inside).
  - **segmentation** - program is divided into parts called segments. Segments sizes are not fixed, so different segments may have different sizes. Program is divided in few segments and each segment will have its own place in RAM (physical) memory. So one segment (call it sementA), and another (call it segmentB) may not be near each other. In other words segmentA don't have to has segmentB as a neighbour.

    **internal fragmentation** - when memory which belongs to process isn't used in 100%. So if process want to have 2 bytes for its use, OS need to allocate page/pages which total size need to be greater or equal than amount of memory requested by program. Typical size of page is 4KB. Unit in which OS gives memory to process are pages. So it can't give less than 4KB. So if we use 2 bytes, 4KB - 2B = 4094 bytes are wasted (memory is associated with our process so other processes can't use it. Only we can use it, but we only need 2B).

    **external fragmentation** - when allocated blocks of memory are one near another, but there is a little hole between them. Its free, so other programs, can use it, but it is unlikly because it is very small. That holes with high probability will be wasted. More holes - more wasted memory.

    Paging may cause effect of internal fragmentation. Segmentation may cause effect of external fragmentation.
- **virtual level** - addresses used in virtual memory. This is extension of logical memory level. Now program don't even need to have all of it's allocated pages in RAM to start execution. It can be implemented with following techniques:

  - **paged segmentation** - method in which segments are divided into pages.
  - **segmented paging** - less used method but also possible.

  Combining them takes a positive aspects from both solutions.

  What i have read about pros and cons of virtual memory:
  **PROS**:

  - processes have their own address space which mean if we have two processes A and B, and both of them have a pointer to address eg. 17 processA pointer will be showing to different frame than pointer in processB. this results in  greater process isolation. Processes are protected from each other (so one process can't do things with another process memory if it isn't shared memory because in its mapping don't exist such mapping entry), and OS is more protected from processes.
  - have more memory than you physical first order memory(RAM, due to swapping to secondary order memory).
  - better use of memory due to:

    - swapping unused parts of programs to secondary memory.
    - making sharings pages possible, also make possible "copy on write".
  - improved multiprogram capability (when not needed parts of programs are swapped out to secondary memory, they made free space in ram which could be used for new procesess.)
  - improved CPU utilisation (if you can have more processes loaded into memory you have bigger probability than there exist some program that now need do CPU stuff, not IO stuff. In such cases you can better utilise CPU).

  **CONS**:

  - virtual memory has it's overhead because we need to get access to memory twice (but here a lot of improvment can be achieved using TLB buffers)
  - it makes OS part managing memory more complicated.

So here we came to parts which I don't really understand:

1. Why in some sources logical address and virtual addresses are described as synonymes? Do I get something wrong?
2. Is really virtual memory making protection to processes? I mean, in segmentation for example there was also check if process do not acces other memory (resulting in segfault if it does), paging also has a protection bit in a page table, so doesn't the protection come from simply extending abstraction of logic level addresses? If VM (Virtual Memory) brings extended protection features, what are they and how they work? In other words: does creating separate address space for each process, bring extended memory protection. If so, what can't be achieved is paging without VM?
3. How really differ paged segmentation from segmented paging. I know that the difference between these two will be how a address is constructed (a page number, segment number, that stuff..), but I suppose it isn't enough to develop 2 strategies. This reason is like nothing. I read that segmented paging is less elastic, and that's the reason why it is rarely used. But why it it less elastic? Is the reason for that, that in program you can have only few segments instead a lot of pages. If thats the case paging indeed allow better "granularity".
4. If VM make separate address space for each process, does it mean, paging without VM use logic addresses from "one pool" (is then every logic address globally unique in that case?).

Any help on that topic would be appreciated.

Edit: #1
Ok. I finally understood that paging not on demand is also a virtual memory. I just found some clarification was helpful to understand the topic. Below is link to image which I made to visualize differences.  Thanks for help.

[differences between paging, demand paging and swapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DI09.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why in some sources logical address and virtual addresses are described as synonymes? Do I get something wrong?

Many sources conflate logical and virtual memory translation. In ye olde days, logical address translation never took place without virtual address translation so processor documentation referred to them as the same.

Now we have large memory systems that use logical memory translation without virtual memory.

> Is really virtual memory making protection to processes?

It is the logical memory translation that implements page protections.

> How really differ paged segmentation from segmented paging.

You can really ignore segments. No rationally designed processor architecture designed after 1970 used segments and they are finally dying out.

> If VM make separate address space for each process, does it mean, paging without VM use logic addresses from "one pool"

It is logical memory that creates the separate address space for each process. Paging is virtual memory. You cannot have one without the other.

Comment: "Paging is virtual memory. You cannot have one without the other."

It's sure that virtual memory couldn't exist without paging because You need something for translating addresses. But what about other way round, paging without virtual memory (call it simple paging)? Is the only difference between this simple paging and paging on demand (which is VM) that swapping in the first one, must swap all pages, and the second may swap only some subset of all? Am i right?

Comment: So after having some sleep, I am able to rephrase question in comment which in fact is much simpler. Is **paging not on demand** also a virtual memory?

Comment: How would you have paging not on demand? I sounds like you are beating around the bush to get at swapping.

Comment: On my university lectures they were as separate things. As i look over the internet it wasn't the only source which claims that. My view about that now it like that: if you have for example 10MB of free RAM, and started  2 processes and one of them wil eat 5MB and the second 5MB. So at this point RAM is full. Now You want to run third process which require 1MB.  In swapping You need to swap out 5MB, load 1MB(for third proc). In paging You will just need to replace 1MB with disk so transer cost will be  2MB, instead of 6MB. So this technique can be more efficient than simple swapping.